# Can't get unique values using a postgres query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the a postgre sql query as follows

```
SELECT cNo,max(numLogs),name,surname FROM details GROUP BY cNo,name,surname
```

and if I run this my results don't group `cNo` instead, is there any way I can get the cNo unique/grouped.

I get the results similar to the following

```
cNo         numLogs     name        surname
23          43          asfas       safdasd
23          45          dsfds       fdsfsdfsd
23          43          dsfsd       dsfsdfsd
```

and I want something like

```
cNo         numLogs     name        surname
23          45          asfas       safdasd
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *only* want the unique `cNo`'s and you don't care about which name / surname you are pulling you can use another aggregate function on those fields.

```
SELECT cNo
    ,max(numLogs)
    ,max(name)
    ,max(surname)
-- min would also work.
FROM details 
GROUP BY cNo
```

Otherwise, what you are pulling is each unique combination of `cNo`, `name`, and `surname`.

If you need to pull a *particular* name or surname (that won't be pulled by `min`, `max` or any of PostGreSQL's [aggregate](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) functions), then you'll want to filter your results rather than selecting everything from the table.